# Can I use a MySQL stored procedure (or some other means) to insert a series rows that reference to-be-created rows from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database for tracking projects. Each project has one or more categories, and each category has one or more tasks.

```
--------
PROJECTS
--------
ID  Name
1   My First Project

----------
CATEGORIES
----------
ID  ProjectID  Name            
1   1          My First Category for Project 1
2   1          My Second Category for Project 1

----------
Tasks
----------
ID  ProjectID  CategoryID  Name            
1   1          1           My First Tasks for Category 1, Project 1
2   1          1           My Second Task for Category 1, Project 1
3   1          2           My First Task for Category 2, Project 1
```

(I know that ProjectID is not required for the Tasks table.)

When a user initiates a new project, I'd like to include a dozen or so default category rows (and their associated default tasks).

Needless to say, I can't execute purely canned INSERT instructions, because I need to know the ID numbers for each newly inserted project before I insert its categories, just as I would need to know each new category's ID before I could insert its tasks.

Of course I can do this with a series of queries, executed with PHP, but I'm wondering if this is something that can be handled with either a stored procedure or some sort of fancier-than-I-know-how-to-write mega query.

Comment: A sproc is possible, but the standard approach would be some PHP script.

Comment: All the standard mysql database extensions provide a way of getting the id of the last row created by an insert. What extension are you using `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: A typical approach would be an `insert` trigger.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I use $db->insert_id in other sections of the code. I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing another method. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @Strawberry: Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks for mentioning the triggers. I think because of the number of unique rows I'll be inserting, and into multiple tables, it seems like PHP will be the easiest approach. Nonetheless, thank you.